# Почему не получается добавить заголовки Access-Control-Allow-Origin?

Tags: ajax, cross-origin

Есть два сайта, второй должен получить контент с первого с помощью json.

Страница второго сайта выдавало ошибку:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load https://адрес первого сайта. Request header field Content-Type is not allowed by Access-Control-Allow-Headers.
```

Я добил такой заголовок в виртуалхостс первого сайта:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "адрес второго сайта"
```

Ошибка та же. Добавил следующий заголовок:

```
Header set Access-Control-Allow-Headers "Origin, X-Requested-With, Content-Type, Accept"
```

В браузе перестало появляться сообщение об ошибке. Но данные по-прежнему не подтягиваются. В чем может быть причина этого?

Comment: Access-Control-Allow-Origin не нуждается в доп. костылях, наверное ты просто забыл рестартовать сервер. а флаг $.ajax({crossDomain: true}) стоит? а что сейчас в ответе сервера? а что в логе бекенда? а что если сделать такой же запрос curl-ом из коммандной строки?

Answer (score 1):

Вероятно, когда браузер посылает запрос `OPNIONS` вместо (точнее, перед, если его устроит ответ) `POST`, ты эти заголовки не добавляешь.